# Stuck after spawning in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A new player spawned on the server for the first time and was spawned inside a tree within the protected area around the spawn. We don't have an admin around, but he is obviously stuck since he can't destroy any block around him and has no way out without destroying something. What can he/we do?

Comment: Is any other player able to get to where he spawned and destroy the blocks around him?

Comment: Is there an op around?  All you need is someone with access to commands.  Alternatively, has the player tried `/kill`?

Comment: no, the problem is the protection of the blocks around the spawn and as stated no op around. `/kill` gave us `permission denied`.

Comment: can you burn the tree?

Comment: First time on the server, so no tools whatsoever. We could get someone else to do it, but i don't think you can do that within the protection zone.

Comment: If you have admins that will be around later, then this is Too Localised in time.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That's not how it works. Besides which, other people might have the same problem in the future.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie to expand on what GnomeSlice said, the main purpose of the Too Localized close reason is to get rid of questions whose solutions will likely only help a single person because the overall *problem* is very specific to a time, geographical location, or person.

Comment: @murgatroid99 TIL something new then! Thanks.

Comment: you can try /suicide. /kill is a command to kill someone else and needs operator permission. /suicide is to kill yourself to get out of such situations.

Comment: @uncovery /kill in vanilla Minecraft kills the player using the command if not provided with a username.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a more long-term solution, since your admin is not around presently as you mentioned, you should consider getting them to add some mods that allow for Admin-style commands.  Plenty of good frameworks already exist that have everything you need - [Essentials](http://www.curse.com/server-mods/minecraft/essentials) is a pretty decent choice.  Using such systems, the ability to manually move a player from one location to another is just a simple matter of using a "teleport" command or such.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is on Hard mode, just walk away. Over time, the player's hunger bar will deplete, causing his life to deplete, until he dies. Since spawning is slightly random, you'll respawn most likely in a different position.

On normal or below, you'll have to get more creative about killing him. If another player can reach him, a simple wooden sword could dispatch him (particularly after starving). If an op can be located, the "/kill" command would work, but I notice you said above that you lack permissions to "/kill" in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have him log out, then fill the space he was standing in, and then have him log back in. Since he can't be placed inside the now-occupied area, he should respawn above it. Repeat this process if necessary until he spawns in a useful location.

As far as I can remember, you can usually *place* objects in the spawn location, although you can't *remove* them once they're there.

Comment: This is not how spawn protection usually works. All blocks are locked, even air.

Comment: Also, your personal spawn point will not change once you've been in a world at all, excepting dying. Filling in the spot would cause them to spawn inside the blocks and take suffocation damage.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie While spawn area rules may differ from server to server, I don't believe what you said for an instant. I have personally witnessed people log out and log back in at a different elevation. The user experience for logging in and instantly suffocating is just stupid. It leads to dead simple griefing.

Comment: @StrixVaria I can only relate my own experience suffocating that way. Then again, in that experience the entire area became "underground", so it may depend on some more complicated code that looks for nearby open space. Or those might have been modded servers with a specific anti-spawn-grief you were observing. \*shrug\* Anyone want to dig into the vanilla code?